# Are these derivatives correct (the respective functions involve a square root, fraction and expansion)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Question: *Use rules of differentiation to answer the following. There is no need to simplify your answer.*

1. If $y = 3x{\sqrt x}$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

My working:

$y = 3x^{1+\frac{1}{2}}$

$y = 3x^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3 \left(\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}-1}\right)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3 \left(\frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{9}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (differentiating $x^n$)

2. If $f(x) = \frac{2x-1}{5x}$, find $f'(x)$

My working:

$f(x) = \frac{2x-1}{5x}$

$f'(x) = \frac{2(1x^{1-1})-1}{5(1x^{1-1})}$

$f(x) = \frac{1}{5}$ (differentiating $x^n$)

3. If $y = (2-3x)^2$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

My working:

$y = 9x^2-12x+4$

$f'(x) = 9(2x^{2-1})-12(1x^{1-1})+0$

$f'(x) = 18x-12$ (differentiating $x^n$ and differentiating a constant)

Comment: Question 1 is fine...

Comment: Question 2 isn't. Use the quotient rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work for Question 1 is fine. For Question 2, use the Quotient Rule (you seem to have assumed that the derivative of a fraction is the derivative of the numerator over the derivative of the denominator, which isn't the case):
\begin{align}
f' \left ( x \right ) & = \frac{5x \cdot 2 - \left ( 2x - 1 \right ) \cdot 5}{\left ( 5x \right )^2} = \frac{1}{5x^2}
\end{align}
In the comments you mentioned that your course permits neither the use of the Product Rule nor of the Quotient Rule. In that case, you can split the numerator into two fractions (this is probably a simpler method anyway, but it wasn't the first way that came to mind):
\begin{align}
f' \left ( x \right ) & = \frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{2 x}{5 x} - \frac{1}{5x} \right ) = \frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{2}{5} - \frac{1}{5x} \right ) = \frac{d}{dx} \left ( - \frac{1}{5x} \right ) = - \frac{1}{5} \left ( - x^{-2} \right ) = \frac{1}{5x^2}
\end{align}
For Question 3, you could have also used the Chain rule, although what you've done is fine.

Comment: For Question 2, does $f'(x) = -\frac{1}{5}x^{-\frac{4}{5}}+\frac{2}{5}$?

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the first term. I think it's just 1/5. Actually, you were right all along (I hadn't done the math until now), but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: No. I'm an idiot. I did the math wrong. Half a sec

Comment: @MadBanners It's 1/(5 x^2). Sorry for the confusion! Updated the answer

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I couldn't find the quotient rule in my textbook so I thought perhaps they wanted me to do it an easier way. Hence my above attempts. @QuantumFool

Comment: @MadBanners Did they give you the product rule? The quotient rule is really the product rule with one function written as 1 over another function. So you could think of f as (1/5x) * (2x - 1) and simplify

Comment: @MadBanners You know the derivative of 1/(5x) is  -1/(5*x^2) by power series

Comment: @MadBanners In more abstract, advanced settings, whenever some (unrelated) operator satisfies the above property, I think of it as a kind of derivative operator. The product rule algebra is very fundamental

Comment: Thank you very much for the tipoff. However, if I use a method which is not in the course, I could be penalised in a test. @QuantumFool

Comment: @MadBanners You could split the numerator into two different fractions and use the derivative of $ x^n $.

Comment: @MadBanners Expanded the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! I should have thought of this. @QuantumFool